# Capturing SOAP faults and handling exceptions

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, fault

I am consuming a web services. Some methods throw exception when i invoked, because the parameters are invalid values, for example. I want to handle the exceptions but it don't contains any data information, only the message "Bad Request". This is my http response:
[image]

```
        try
        {
            var data = client.SomeMethod(4);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // exception.Message = Bad Request
            // exception don't contains any more data information
        }
```

How can I capture the other information

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can catch the exception with `FaultException` when the http status code is 2xx or 5xx, not 4xx. You can catch the http status code 4xx with `System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException` and then get the stream from the `InnerException` and parse it or get the FaultException from this stream. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nathana/archive/2011/03/31/deciphering-a-soap-fault-with-a-400-status-code.aspx for more details.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this is a WCF web service? You are catching to wide of an exception. Try with a [`FaultException<TDetail>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms576199%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

> Typical deployed services use the FaultContractAttribute to formally specify all SOAP faults that a client can expect to receive in the normal course of an operation. Error information in a FaultContractAttribute appears as a FaultException (where the typeparameter is the serializable error object specified in the operation's FaultContractAttribute) when it arrives at a client application. The FaultContractAttribute can be used to specify SOAP faults for both two-way service methods and for asynchronous method pairs.
>
> Because FaultException is both a FaultException and therefore a CommunicationException, to catch specified SOAP faults make sure you catch the FaultException types prior to the FaultException and CommunicationException types or handle the specified exceptions in one of those exception handlers.

Comment: I did not know about FaultException<TDetail>, however I can't capture any FaultExecption, only CommunicationException, but this don't have any information. I don't create the service.

Answer (score 1):

You can use try-catch like below. Then you can access other information. You have to find the "TDetail". It provides by the web service.

```
catch(FaultException<TDetail> ex)
{
    ex.Code.ToString();
    ex.Reason.ToString();
}
```

Other way.

```
FaultException faultException = (FaultException)ex;
MessageFault msgFault = faultException.CreateMessageFault();
XmlElement elm = msgFault.GetDetail<XmlElement>();
```

Comment: It works fine, in my case I had no definition for the TDetail since my library was closed and a third-party legacy solution... By casting to FaultException I could get the full XML response and format the full error message with detail, I voted your answer man